# Wordpress: retrieve first five items from all populated categories

Tags: wordpress, categories

I am trying to find a way to achive the following: I'd like to make a custom template. Within this template I'd like to list the name of each category on my site that has at least 1 item assigned to it. Beneath the category name (and link) I'd like to insert some content from the first x number of items that have that particular category assigned.

Just in case it makes a massive difference the items in question are not posts, but custom items.

Can anyone give me some pointers or help? I assume there will be something I can do with the wp_query function, but I'm not really sure how to inject it between each of the category titles, or indeed how to make it work with a category for which I can't explicitly provide an id in the code).

Thank you.

Comment: You say custom items, you mean a custom table in the database? Or something like usermeta?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[get_posts()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) is your ideal solution. For example:

```
<?php $posts_array = get_posts( $args ); ?>

<?php $args = array(
'posts_per_page'   => 1,
'category'         => $post_cat,
'orderby'          => 'post_date',
'order'            => 'DESC',
'post_type'        => 'yourcustompostname',
'post_status'      => 'publish',
'suppress_filters' => true ); 


$myposts = get_posts( $args );

///respective loop here ie : foreach $myposts as $mypost ... etc

?>
```

Where `$post_cat` is the id of your category and `post_type` is the custom post type.

To keep these 'items' organized I would create a [custom post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types) and then assign a category to those posts, for each respective category (if there are multiple). If there is just one, than you could live with just using a single category.

EDIT:

to get the categories assigned to this custom post take a look at this [link](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/list-categories-for-custom-post-type)

Using the results from this you could assign the cat id's to the variable created earlier: `$post_cat`.

Comment: Thanks, this looks good. My problem is how to get this to fire for each category that exists, without knowing what those categories are beforehand. The end-user will have the freedom to create new categories so I need to create a page that automatically checks what categories exist and are being used, then does the above for each of those...

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `query_posts` function

`query_posts(array('category_name'=>'category-slug','posts_per_page'=>'5'));`

then you need to do

`while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();`

and you can get the post id using:

`$p_id = get_the_ID();`

for more information : [query_posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts)

Comment: Will that group things into category by category sets?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `get_categories()`

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories

But, then you need to find out where the data for 'items' is stored, and query depending on that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer of your problem. You need to change the category id of own post category id . 
Here is the code. just copy and past it.

```
$query1 = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'post','cat' =>'10,9') );
```

Use the above query in loop and after loop,reset your query . see the below code.

```
wp_reset_query();
```

Please use it and let me know if needs anything else.